# How to ask in Chinese: What do you want to come to talk to me about?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence

你想去对我说 means you want to go to speak to me.

How to ask a question: What do you want to come to talk to me about? I don't know where to put the word `什么`.

Is `你想去对我说什么` correct?

How to say a normal sentence (not a question): This is what I want to go to speak to you.

Is `這就是 我想去对你说什么` correct?

How to ask a question: Is this what you want to come to speak to me?

Comment: "What do you want to go to speak to me?" seems peculiar in English.  It seems like you are asking someone what they want (some kind of payment) to go somewhere to speak to "me" (so there are two "me"s: the person speaking, and the person to go to).  Maybe this could arise in sci-fi, e.g. you're paying a time traveler to travel back in time to speak to you (in the past).

Comment: Sorry, English is not my mother language. But now I do realize I should use `come` instead of `go`.

Comment: Even with `go` instead of `come`, `What do you want to come to speak to me?` is still a very peculiar, un-idiomatical sentence. It still means, as @Becky李蓓 mentioned, "what payment or reward do you want for coming to speak to me?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normal sentence: This is what I want to go to speak to you. 這就是我想跟你說的。

question: Is this what you want to go to speak to me? 這就是你想跟我說的？

Comment: It is the same. You just added a ? mark at the end. Or don't  I see it right?

Comment: @OConnor first one is "我想跟你說的", second one is  "你想跟我說的".

Comment: The English in this answer is not idiomatic, and is not a good translation of the Chinese, so I am downvoting this answer.

Comment: I would upvote @HungYuChang one more if I could. Because it is here to help each other learn things. At least, HungYu Chang did give me answers how I can speak in Chinese in that context. 1. My questions were not about how to ask in English. 2. It is here not to always give you exact answers but to help you find a way to go further. With all respect to your time goPlayerJuggler, you did not even give one answer, just complained here and there.

Answer (score 3):

O'Connor sounds Irish: maybe you only speak Gaelic?

Perhaps you mean:

What do you want to speak to me about?
你想跟我说什么？
你想跟我聊什么？

Answer (score 0):

Using 去 in "你想去对我说" is not appropriate.  People 'come to me' not 'go to me'. It should be either 你想来对我说什么?" or  "你想对我说什么?"

> *How to say a normal sentence (not a question): This is what I want to go to speak to you.*

> *Is 這就是 我想去对你说什么 correct?*

It is "這就是我想对你说的" (This is what I want to say to you)

> *"Is this what you want to go to speak to me"*

It should be no '去' in the sentence or replace '去' with '来' when the object is "我"

"Is this what you want to speak to me?" =  "這就是你想对我说的?"

Comment: How to ask a question: Is this what you want to go to speak to me?

Comment: It is the same. You just added a ? mark at the end. Or don't I see it right?

Comment: "這就是(我)想对(你)说的."  is different from "這就是(你)想对(我)说的?"

Comment: The English in this answer is not idiomatic, and is not a good translation of the Chinese, so I am downvoting this answer.

Comment: I didn't come up with the English sentence, I just translate what is in from of me. It is not my intention to rewrite the directly translated sentence into more native Chinese. And my translation is accurate

Comment: I would upvote @TangHo one more if I could. Because it is here to help each other learn things. At least, TangHo spent his valuable time typing information what I can learn from. 1. My questions were not about how to ask in English. 2. It is here not to always give you exact answers but to help you find a way to go further. With all respect to your time goPlayerJuggler, you did not even give one answer, just complained here and there.