# Are 我听不清你说了的 and 我听不见你说了的 both correct?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I want to say:

I did not hear what you said.
Is it `我听不见你说了的` correct?

I did not hear clearly what you said.
Is it `我听不清你说了的` correct?

Comment: Use 说了什么 instead of 说了的

Comment: But it is not a question. It is more like `I did not hear the thing you said`. Still need to use `什么` instead of  `的`?

Comment: 什么  here  is  just like 'what' in 'what you have said is correct!'  And 'what' doesn't make the sentence a question, it is more like  a pronoun

Comment: Don't add 了 or change the position of 了. 我聽不見你說的(了) or  我聽不清你說的(了) would be more fluent.

Comment: I tought [verb + 了] makes it a past tense e.g. 說 = speak, 說了 = spoke. What does 了 do at the end of the sentence?

Comment: 了 at the end of a sentence makes the sentence past tense. Using it after the verb vs. at the end of the sentence are not necessarily equivalent. I'm not a native speaker at all so the rules governing this aren't clear to me, but my impression is in this sentence 说的 together is a unit (you can think of 的 after the verb as turning it into a noun). "说“ meaning "say/said", ”说的“ meaning "the thing that was said". If I'm wrong about this, I hope some native speaker can correct me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

听不见 and 听不清 mean different things.

- 听不见 = can't hear/ didn't hear (didn't know you spoke)
- 听不清 = can't clearly hear (unsure what you are saying)

Use '**听不见你说的話**' [didn't hear the words you said] or '**听不见你说了什么** [didn't hear what you have said] instead of '听不见你说了的' [didn't hear that you have said] (object missing)

'听不见你(剛)说了的(話)' is also acceptable, but kind of wordy.

Comment: I have learned this `這就是我想对你说的 = This is what I want to say to you` from you on another question https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/40825/how-to-ask-in-chinese-what-do-you-want-to-come-to-speak-to-me?noredirect=1#comment60996_40825. Based on your answer, I should not use `什么` to refer to `what` if it is not a question. You show me to put `的` at the end of the sentence. But here I should to `什么` instead of `的`. But both sentences are not a question. Could you please explain me a bit more. Thanks in advance!

Comment: 這 in 這就是我想对你说的 refers to  an aforementioned statement. We know what was said;  什么 in '听不见你说了什么 refers to an unknown statement, we don't know what was said

Comment: `我听不见你说的`, `我听不见你说的了`, `我听不清你说的` and `我听不清你说的了` are all correct setences?

Comment: All seem to miss the object--   我听不见你说的(話), 我听不见你说的(話)了, 我听不清你说的(話) and 我听不清你说的(話)了; Also, If you treat 了as a final particle, it only serves to emphasize the sentence, add emotion, and soften the tone of the speech;  If you treat 了as a verb particle, then 了 indicates either the completion of the verb or change of situation. Please search question about the usage of 了 to learn its functions in adifferent contexts

Answer (score 5):

Try 我没听见你说的 or 你说的我没听见.

Other alternatives: 你说的话我没听见 or 没听见你说的是什么.  什么 can also work as a pronoun here.

我没听清你说什么 is *I didn't hear clearly what you said.*

说了的 is not a correct phrase.

Comment: Is 说的 is a correct phrase?

Comment: @OConnor yes, it's an attributive phrase.

Answer (score 3):

"I did not hear clearly what you said." sounds a bit "stiff", English people often use 'catch' for this.

When someone says something to you, but you didn't hear clearly, so you don't understand, you could write:

Sorry, I didn't quite catch what you said.
对不起，我没听懂你说的话。

Someone says something to you, but you are not really paying attention:

Sorry, I didn't hear what you said.
对不起，我没听到你说的话。

And, when you can't understand anything a person is saying to you (like me quite often):

It's all Greek to me!
一窍不通。

Answer (score 1):

I did not hear what you said. => 我没听见你说的话
I did not hear clearly what you said. => 我没听清你说的话

我听不见你说了的 => I can not hear what you said
我听不清你说了的 => I can not hear clearly what you said

我听不见 means you may have an issue in your ear to hear or it is a noisy environment to make you can not hear, it is an objective reason. On the contrary,  我没听见 is a subjective reason.

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct, but a bit formal, the following ones are used more often in daily conversation.

1. 我没听见你说的啥
2. 我没听清你说的啥